# Displaying the best products in the home page of a Magento Store Community edition v1.7

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display the best products of the demo store Community edition v1.7 on the home page,
first I tried to install an extension called **Magento Bestseller Products Extension** from this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bestseller-products-7401.html, but it didn't work

so I decided to output best products myself,

to achieve this I have created two files:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/MyBestSeller.php
app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/product/mybestseller.phtml
```

and I added this line to the home page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_mybestseller" template="catalog/product/mybestseller.phtml"}}
```

then I refreshed the cache

My problem is that nothing is outputed!
Is it the right way to output data in the home page?

Here is the code of MyBestSeller.php

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_MyBestSeller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize(6)->setCurPage(1);

    $this->setProductCollection($products);
}
```

}

and mybestseller.phtml starts like this (I think the rest of the code is not important that's why I didn't included it):

```
<h2 style="background-color: red">from myestseller.phtml</h2><!-- just a test -->

<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = count($_products->getItems()) ?>
<table class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You should do this as a separate module in /app/code/local/YOU/MODULENAME

Comment: Have you turned on template hints in the admin ?  its in system>configuration>advanced>developer, see if your template is actually being invoked.

Comment: @russjman I tried to do it in a separate module, but I get no output, and I have turned the tmplate hints on, but I see no hints in the frontend, but I found some errors in /var/exception.log I will post them

Comment: 2012-07-10T22:02:15+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type of bloc invalid : Mage_Mymodule_Block_Bestseller' in /home/index/public_html/mystore/app/Mage.php:594

Comment: Invalid block type and not Type of bloc invalid (I tried to translate from french :) )

Comment: Make sure your module is being recognized by Magento. Check in the admin under System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced.  If you initialized your module correctly...it should show up there.

Comment: Also...since your module is now separate from the magento core the class needs to reflect this in order to be found by Magento. So  Mage_Mymodule_Block_Bestseller is now YOU_MODULENAME_Block_Bestseller...

Comment: I checked the module appear in Configurations->Advanced. I just created a new module with very simple code and template, but when I access the index page of the module it renders correctly and when I add a block to it I get an exception Invalid block type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed my problem by turning off compilation from System->Tools->Compilation->Disable